# Natural Numbers Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have attached the question with my attempt to a solution, noting where I get stuck.  I try to prove using induction, although I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach the problem.  Tips, suggestions, and hints would be very helpful.  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Think about even and odd numbers.

Comment: what specifically about even and odd numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need induction. Rather, separate two cases:

1. $a$ is even. Then, if $a$ is even, $a=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, meaning that $$\frac{a(a^2+1)}{2} = \frac{2k(4k^2+1)}{2} = \dots$$
2. $a$ is odd. Then $a=2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, so $$\frac{a(a^2+1)}{2} = \dots$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still slightly confused.  Lets say for the first case, I simplify the expression to 4k^3+k.  Is it known fact that a natural number raised to a power is a natural number, that a natural number times another natural number, (4 in this case), is a natural number, and that 2 natural numbers added together are natural or do I have to prove these results?

Comment: @kemb If you don't understand that a product of two natural numbers is a natural numbers, then you have to go back and re-read some other chapters in either your lecture notes or the book you are learning from...

Comment: @kemb "A product of two integers is an integer" is something true by definition (we define the product as a mapping from $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$. If you do not understand this, then you need to go back to basics...

Comment: I would like to ask whoever downvoted my question to also explain why he thinks my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @kemb Then your text is not basic enough.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Solution 1:}$ (Without induction)

Let $a\in \Bbb N.$ If $a$ is even then $a=2k$ for some integer $k.$ Hence

$$\frac{a(a^2+1)}{2}=k(4k^2+1)\in \Bbb N.$$ On the other hand, if $a$ is odd, then $a=2k+1$ for some integer $k.$ Now we find

$$\frac{a(a^2+1)}{2}=(2k+1)(2k^2+ 2k +1)\in \Bbb N.$$ $\Box$

$\textbf{Solution 2:}$ (Using induction)

Here basically we do the same as you did, and perform a similar analysis as in the previous solution when you get stuck. So it suffices to prove that 
$$\frac{(3a-2)(a-1)}{2} \in \Bbb N.$$ If $a=2k,$ then 
$$\frac{(3a-2)(a-1)}{2}= (3k-1)(2k-1)\in \Bbb N. $$ If $a=2k+1$ then

$$\frac{(3a-2)(a-1)}{2}= (6k+1)k\in \Bbb N. $$ $\Box$

Comment: The second solution doesn't really use induction at all...

Comment: Yes it does. The induction part is in the work of @kemb. I just took it from where he got stuck. You should read before downvote

Comment: OK, point taken.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up where OP's induction attempt left off...

> Need to show this implies $\displaystyle\frac{(k+1)\big((k+1)^2+1\big)}{2} \in \mathbb{N}\,$.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(k+1)\big((k+1)^2+1\big)}{2} &= \frac{(k+1)(k^2+1+2k+1)}{2} \\
 &= \frac{k(k^2+1)+k(2k+1)+k^2+1+2k+1}{2} \\
 &= \frac{k(k^2+1)}{2}+\frac{3k(k+1)}{2}+\frac{2}{2}
\end{align}
$$

The first term in the latter sum is an integer by the induction hypothesis, the last one is integer $1\,$, and the middle one is an integer because the product $k(k+1)$ of two consecutive integers is always even (since one of them must itself be even).

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Of course, the induction-less proof is more direct: $$\frac{a(a^2+1)}{2} = \frac{a(a^2-1+2)}{2}=\frac{(a-1)\,a\,(a+1)}{2}+a\,$$

Again, the first term is an integer since there is always an even amongst two consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

So show that:$$\forall a\in \mathbb{N},\frac{a(a^2 +1)}{2}\in \mathbb{N}$$
The question is in the set $ \mathbb{N}$ so we should using induction

$\frac{a(a^2 +1)}{2}\in \mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow $ $2|a(a^2 +1)$

1) check $P(1)$: $\frac{1(1^2 +1)}{2} =\frac{2}{2} =1\in \mathbb{N}$ (True)

2) suppose $P(k)\in \mathbb{N}$ is true ($k\in \mathbb{N}$) so $\forall k\in \mathbb{N},\frac{k(k^2 +1)}{2}\in \mathbb{N}$ is true

3) prove $P(k+1)\in \mathbb{N}$ is also true:$$\frac{(k+1)((k+1)^2 +1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{(k+1)(k^2 +2k+2)}{2}$$ $$=\frac{k^3+3k^2+4k+2}{2}$$ $$=\frac{(k^3+k)+(2k^2+2k+2)+(k^2+k)}{2}$$ $$=\underbrace{\frac{k(k^2+1)}{2}}+\underbrace{\frac{2(k^2+k+1)}{2}}+\underbrace{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}$$ $2|k(k^2+1)$ $\rightarrow $ proven in $P(k)$

$2|2(k^2+k+1)$ $\rightarrow $ as we see.

$2|k(k+1)$ $\rightarrow $  the product of two consecutive integers is always even( because if the first is odd so the second is even, or if the second is odd so the first is even).

So $P(k+1)\in \mathbb{N}$ is True.

Finally we prove by Induction $\forall a\in \mathbb{N},\frac{a(a^2 +1)}{2}\in \mathbb{N}$